# react slick align content and slider on the same container inline

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

i am trying to have flex where my left section will have some content and right section will have the slider, but when i apply flex to main container its not showing the slider.

How to fix this

App.js

```
import "./styles.css";
import Slider from "react-slick";
import "slick-carousel/slick/slick.css";
import "slick-carousel/slick/slick-theme.css";


export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className={"container"}>
      <div className={"user"}>Hai</div>
      <div className={"sliderSection"}>
        <Slider dots slidesToShow={3}>
          {[1, 2, 3, 4].map((d) => (
            <div>{d}</div>
          ))}
        </Slider>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

style.css

```
.container {
  width: calc(100% - 194px);
  margin: 0 auto 20px auto;
  display: flex;
  border: solid 1px;
}

.user {
  width: 140px;
  height: 180px;
  background-color: red;
}

.sliderSection {
  margin-left: 30px;
}
```

[Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/rough-worker-fj69hl)

Comment: Unsolicited advice: I recently explored different slider options (including react slick) and ended up going with https://swiperjs.com/. It works better in all respects in my experience.

Comment: @SlavaKnyazev Thanks for the info but can't add a new package for this issue. Is there any way to solve it

Answer (score 1):

I have done some changes in index.css and app component. Sharing those changes below. Please check if it works for you.

App Component :

```
import "./styles.css";
import Slider from "react-slick";
import "slick-carousel/slick/slick.css";
import "slick-carousel/slick/slick-theme.css";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className={"container"}>
      <div className={"user"}>Hai</div>
      <div className={"sliderSection"}>
        <Slider className={'slider'} dots slidesToShow={3}>
          {[1, 2, 3, 4].map((d) => (
            <div key={d} >{d}</div>
          ))}
        </Slider>
      </div>
    </div>

    )
  }
```

Css file:

```
.container {
  width: calc(100% - 194px);
  margin: 0 auto 20px auto;
  display: flex;
  border: solid 1px;
}

.user {
  width: calc(100% - 130px);
  height: 180px;
  background-color: red;
}

.sliderSection {
  background-color: orange;
  width: 100%;
  display : flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items : center;
}

.slider{
  width: 60px;
}
```

Note : I have done above changes on mobile device. You might need to adjust the size.

Comment: It helped, one doubt If i move the map rendered div to another component why is it not working 
https://codesandbox.io/s/unruffled-haze-q6mc2v?file=/src/Another.jsx, can you check this

Comment: Sorry for very delayed response. <Slider> </Slider> component accepts index elements as a child. We need to pass the number of option elements inside the Slider component.. instead of using <Another /> try using { Another() } function call. Set stylings according to your requirement. I had updated the .slider class for mobile view. Set the width to 40px